# How to create WPF window with exact pixel size?

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to display a window in my application exactly in specified rectangle:

`Left = 0, Top = 0, Width = 1920, Height = 240`.

It seems to have left and right margin. And a bottom margin. Looks roughly like 8 pixels. Like the system refused to place the window where I told it to by specifying Left, Top, Width and Height properties.

However when I set `WindowStyle` to `None` and `AllowsTransparency` to `True`- it behaves properly.

But I don't need and I don't want borderless windows, I need normal system windows, but placed correctly. How to achieve it?

If the margins are the part of Windows UI and can't be removed - how to determine their sizes to take into account when placing windows?

I'm testing it with Windows 10 on desktop computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***It's*** cause there is no design border in `windows 10` like `windows 7`. Use below code to set the `Left` property:

```
Left = 0 - SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth - SystemParameters.FixedFrameVerticalBorderWidth;
```

your `window's` position will be right after this.  Top should be already OK. Set `Width` equal to `SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width`then there should be no margin to Right.

Comment: I've just tested it, and it works fine, but should this correction be used with Windows 7 too?

Comment: @Harry Nope. This can't be used with Window 7. If you want your app to run in both OS. you have to put a check of OS before you set the property.