# WPF - Incorrect Window resolution after setting Window.Windowstate to Maximized programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windowstate

So I'm trying to open a maximized Window on my secondary monitor. It all works fine, except it's height is 2 pixels lower than it should be.

My secondary monitor has a resolution of 1280x1024. However once I inspect the window, it's 1280x1022. Does anyone know the problem?

OS: Windows 10

[Actual height/width image (Puush)](http://puu.sh/oLzOr/4920e3da26.png)

Here is some code:

```
SecondaryMonitorWindow smw = new SecondaryMonitorWindow();
smw.Show();
```

**XAML**

```
Loaded="OnWindowLoaded"
WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
WindowStyle="None"
SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
Height="1280" 
Width="1024"
```

**Constructor**

```
public SecondaryMonitorWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Instance = this;
}
```

**Event**

```
private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MaximizeToSecondaryMonitor();
}
```

**ExtensionMethod**

```
public static void MaximizeToSecondaryMonitor(this Window window)
{
    var secondaryScreen = Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Where(s => !s.Primary).FirstOrDefault();

    if (secondaryScreen != null)
    {
        if (!window.IsLoaded)
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

        window.Left = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left;
        window.Top = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top;
        window.Width = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        window.Height = secondaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

        if (window.IsLoaded)
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: @KyloRen Added it to the description, but I'm using Windows 10 atm.

Comment: did it help? or still not getting your desired output?

Comment: @KyloRen In your [linked post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529885/how-to-create-wpf-window-with-exact-pixel-size/35529943#35529943) they said that once he allowed transparency, it worked. So I did add that to the XAML, and then it worked fine. I also added 'window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;' in the extension method. To ensure it isn't set to maximized in the XAML (which would still force open it in the primary monitor). However, when I applied your original fix, it still calculated the height with 2 pixels off. But in some sense you've helped me anyway! Thanks!

Comment: but are you ok with Window.Style = none?

Comment: @KyloRen My WindowStyle is set to None yea. But I was referring to WindowState tho. (Maximized/Minimized/Normal)

Comment: I'm skeptical about the results with mentioned settings but if you are saying then probably you have achieved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the parameter grammatically, this way only you'll be able to achieve the perfect size :

```
 public MainWindow()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
        this.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
    }
```

however there are bugs around `Window 10`. if you are using please let me know I'll update the answer.

For Window 10 [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529885/how-to-create-wpf-window-with-exact-pixel-size/35529943#35529943)  will help. there are no design `Border` in window 10 so there is some pixel problem. I'm not sure what is `Window` decoration settings on your OS, but try this.

```
this.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height +  SystemParameters.FixedFrameHorizontalBorderHeight;
this.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width + SystemParameters.FixedFrameVerticalBorderWidth;
```

If there were some other borders are removed try `ResizeFrame` border size addition too.